# GCC packed struct including unpacked struct is packed in 4.4.3

Tags: gcc, struct, packed

Consider the following code from [ttyrpld 2.60](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ttyrpld/) `include/rpl_packet.h`:

```
struct rpltime {
    uint64_t tv_sec;
    uint32_t tv_usec;
};

union rpldev_evmagic {
    uint32_t n;
    char m[4];
};

struct rpldsk_packet {
    union rpldev_evmagic evmagic;
    uint32_t size;
    struct rpltime time;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

That is, `rpltime` is not packed, `rpldsk_packet` that includes an `rpltime` member is packed.

If you take the `sizeof struct rpldsk_packet` using ppc_85xxDP-gcc (GCC) 4.2.2 from the ELDK distribution, you get 24. Using gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3 you get 20. That is, `struct rpltime` is also packed on the Ubuntu GCC. According to the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html), I would expect that the `sizeof` would be 24 with any GCC, incuding gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3.

Did the behavior of the `packed` attribute regarding unpacked members change between 4.2.2 and 4.4.3? and if so, when? Or is the documentation out-of-date? What did I miss?

Comment: I get 24 with gcc-4.7.2. Seems to be a bug in 4.4.3.

Comment: The answer is that it depends on word length. On 64 bit machines (PPC) the sizeof will be 24, on 32 bit machines it will be 20. No bug in GCC. If someone cares to write this up I will mark as answered.